# Enumerate which fields are different between two objects in Dart

Tags: dart

Let say I have a class:

```
class Person {
    final String name;
    final int age;
    final DateTime created;
    final List<Pet> pets;
}
```

In Dart, how do I list all the fields that are different between 2 instances e.g. between "original" and "updated" instances? I only need a shallow (`==`) check for each field, including collection fields (e.g. `pets`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function

```
 class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  List<Pet> pets;

  void enumerateDifferences(Person other) {
    if (this.name != other.name) {
      print("Name is different");
    } else if (this.age != other.age) {
      print("Age is different");
    } else if (pets != other.pets) {
      //If shallow compare
      print("Pets is differenct");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any "reflective" approach?

Comment: import 'dart:mirrors'; 
this is the only library which is not available in flutter.
https://mrale.ph/blog/2017/01/08/the-fear-of-dart-mirrors.html
read this article